# How can I use multi-line match clauses that return values in rust?

Tags: rust

For a toy example, say I'd like to make a cache for files on disk and log its output. Here's what I hoped would work:

```
struct Cache {
    data: HashMap<String, String>
}

impl Cache {
    fn load(&mut self, filename: &str) -> String {
        let result = match self.data.get(filename) {
            Some(s) => s.clone(),
            None => {
                let s = fs::read_to_string(filename).expect("couldn't read");
                self.data.insert(String::from(filename), s.clone());
                return s;
            }
        };
        println!("my result: {}", result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

But the `None => {...}` clause isn't executed like its own function, so its `return` exits the whole `load` function. I tried a couple different ways, but couldn't get multi-line match clauses to return a value. Is there any way to get this type of `match` working in rust?

rust version: 1.50.0
language edition: 2018

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The final statement in a block is returned, that applies to any block, i.e. if you put `s` as the last line in the `None` match arm, it will be returned from that block.

So you should change that arm to

```rust
            None => {
                let s = fs::read_to_string(filename).expect("couldn't read");
                self.data.insert(String::from(filename), s.clone());
                s
            }
```

Note: there is no `return` and no `;` either.

You only need to use `return` when returning from a function or closure.